# Facebook ignores Default Activity Privacy setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I have set my app's Default Activity Privacy to "Only me", but when showing an auth dialog, Facebook ignores this setting and always shows "Friends". I am not mistaken about the expected behaviour. It is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/.

Even when I preview the dialog within the app settings page, it shows "Friends" instead of "Only me". What gives?

Comment: are you sure ? Because I just created an app for you and it seems to be working 

https://apps.facebook.com/for-steven/

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I found a bug report anyway: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/268481063205627

Answer (score 0):

Because your Facebook account already accept the application with default privacy is "Friends". You can change it.  
Go to your Facebook page, then go to Privacy Settings, then choose Applications: http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications  
Find the app you are talking about, you will see the current privacy is "Friends". You can change it here.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question. This is a facebook *developer* question, not a user question. Note about that a bug report for this already existing at the time I wrote the question. The link is dead now, so maybe it's fixed.